# Encoding format (tmp) is not supported for image resize laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to resize uploaded image and store in folder.then show in web.
i used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on form in blade.php.
file successfully show in web without resize. 
when try to resize image i got error

controller.php

```
public function dili(Request $request)
{
    $di = new diligent;


    $di->jobtype = $request->jobtype;
    $di->jobC = $request->jobC;
    $di->details = $request->details;

    $image = $request->file('image');
    $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath = public_path('img');

    Image::make($image)->resize(300, 100)->save($image);
    $a = $image->move($destinationPath, $path);

    $di->image = $path;
    $di->save();
    $de = diligent::all();

    return view('admin')->with('dw', $de);
}
```

Error Message

Encoding format (tmp) is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use  **getRealPath()** inside **Image::make()**

2) save image in particular path. try like this.

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image       = $request->file('image');
    $filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
    $image_resize->resize(300, 100);
    $image_resize->save(public_path('img/' .$filename));
}
```

Make sure you installed **Image intervention** library.

The Intervention image **save()** method requires a filename so it knows what file format (jpg, png, etc..) to save your image in.

The reason you are getting the error is it does not know what encoding to save the temporary image object **(tmp)** in.

Here is an example

```
->save('my-image.jpg', 90)
```

There is also a optional second parameter that controls the quality output. The above outputs at 90% quality.

http://image.intervention.io/api/save

Comment: still got same error   Encoding format (tmp) is not supported.

Comment: i think reason is file encoded with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  in html form.

Comment: Can you do one thing. `print_r($request->file('image'))` and edit your answer.

Comment: got error as  SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10...' for column `diligentdb`.`diligents`.`image` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `diligents` (`jobtype`, `jobC`, `details`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values hello, namr, hello;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 90

Comment: This error is from mySQL while you're saving records.

Comment: Got your solution?

Comment: yes i got solution....your solution worked... ` $di->image = $filename;` edited like this

Comment: Oh!! you were saving path that's why error from mysql.

Comment: This does not work for me using laravel  8